# newsstand app without subscriptions

Tags: ios, subscription, newsstand-kit

Back in iOS 5 days Newsstand-Apps needed to have a subscription option. Also if the app only offers free issues, there had to be at least a free subscription.

after downloading a bunch of apps from the iOS app store (newsstand section), many of them don't include a option to subscribe. Does Apple accept Newsstand-Apps that don't offer subscriptions?

i can't find any hints in the documentation that handle this topic?

anybody knows whats the current state of this "issue" ?

Comment: Last I heard on this, the app does not need to have a subscription option, but a (potentially) free subscription option must exist in iTunes connect, and there may be certain sub-realted entitlements that you'd need to handle in the app. But you do not need to require the user to actually subscribe to anything. (my knowledge of this is over 1 yr old)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There are a lot of Newsstand which do not require subscription. The same topic is discussed [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1347170). You can even get a tutorial to develop free newsstand app [here](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/).

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think so apple accepts coz in one of app c&en developed by me doesn't have any free subscription, but app already provide free toc. You can check that app on App Store.

[C&EN](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/c-en-mobile/id451789640?mt=8)